# sim() function from rethinking package not working, unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sim’ for signature ‘"map"’

Tags: r

This is quite strange. I have been working with the rethinking package for some time now without any problem. All of a sudden, the sim() function (used to draw posterior predictive samples) is not working anymore. I can't even reproduce Richard McElreath's Statistical Rethinking book code. For instance, when I try to run

```r
## R code 4.42
# load data again, since it's a long way back
library(rethinking)
data(Howell1); d <- Howell1; d2 <- d[ d$age >= 18 , ]

# define the average weight, x-bar
xbar <- mean(d2$weight)

# fit model
m4.3 <- quap(
  alist(
    height ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) ,
    mu <- a + b*( weight - xbar ) ,
    a ~ dnorm( 178 , 20 ) ,
    b ~ dlnorm( 0 , 1 ) ,
    sigma ~ dunif( 0 , 50 )
  ) , data=d2 )

## R code 4.54
# define sequence of weights to compute predictions for
# these values will be on the horizontal axis
weight.seq <- seq( from=25 , to=70 , by=1 )

## R code 4.59
sim.height <- sim( m4.3 , data=list(weight=weight.seq) )
str(sim.height)
```

I get the following message

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sim’ for signature ‘"map"’

Any idea what might be going on here? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I just installed `rethinking` and re-ran your code. I don't get any errors, and `sim` works just fine. My feeling is that you re-defined `sim` somewhere in your code, or that you've loaded another package that provides a `sim` function that overrides `rethinking::sim`. To test, replace `sim.height <- sim(m4.3, data = list(weight = weight.seq))` with `sim.height <- rethinking::sim(m4.3, data = list(weight = weight.seq))`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers That solved my problem!! Still, no clue about what might have caused the clash